# How to extract the title image of the web page

Tags: asp.net, html, regex, page-title, asp.net-webpages

I want to extract the title image of a web page using C# in ASP.NET. I checked the windows and document objects but they don't have a property such as title. So searching for method to extract the title image like in the page tab of the Chrome.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to get this from a console or a winforms app by parsing an `aspx` page? Are you programming an asp.net app and simply want to get/set the title programmatically? If the latter, you should be looking at `Page.Title`

Comment: What do you mean by "title" image?  Do you mean the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)?

Comment: HTML doesn't have a "title image". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I believe he wants the favicon

Comment: Yep, The image source that is stored on Chrome Tab is favicon.

Comment: Try downloading http://{websiteaddress}/favicon.ico

Comment: Yes favicon. I want the image that appears in the tab of the chrome window. Like the Facebook, Youtube etc.

Comment: I am using asp.net to extract the favicon for using in the aspx page.

Comment: Are you trying to get the favicon of a web site, or are you trying to set one for your webpage?

Comment: I am storing bookmarks so want to get the image along with the title in asp.net aspx page.

Comment: any webpage icon that the user will like to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  Byte[] favico = client.DownloadData("http://msite.com/favico.ico");
}
```

That's using [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f). You can also use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe) if you're looking to store it.

A further bullet-proofed approach would be to download the index page and use an HTML parser to look for the `<link>` tag that specifies where the icon is supposed to be (could also be applied to apple-touch-icon or otherwise).

BTW, the tags I believe you're looking to parse are:

```
<!-- StackOverflow's implementation: -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.../favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.../apple-touch-icon.png">

<!-- Google's implementation: -->
<meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image">

<!-- Facebook's implementation: -->
<link href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/.../q9U99v3_saj.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Comment: Note that this isn't always true.  Only IE up to version 8 looks for the icon in the root of the site automatically.  All other browser, as well as IE9, look for `<link rel="icon" href="..."/>` tag in the document.  The path may be anything you like - and not necessarily root.

Comment: @AleksG: Thus my addendum about a more robust solution in the second paragraph, but thanks for the follow-up details.

Comment: for the parsing I suppose to use regular expressions?

Comment: @user1575229: I would advise against it; You're better off using a DOM/HTML parser. Either [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) or you may be able to instantiate a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) in ASP and use its parser (though I'm not sure that's ideal given it's an ASP application and WebBrowser is a WinForms class. You'll also get a lot of unnecessary overhead given the purpose of a WebBrower control--a lot to load just for DOM parsing).

Comment: Love the typo: `StockOverflow` :)

Comment: @MennanKara: Good catch, oops! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as "title image" in HTML specifications.  The icon you see in the tab or near the URL in some browser is specified using `<link rel="icon"/>` construct:

```
<link type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
```

IE may rquire you to use a slightly different syntax:

```
<link type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut" />
```

Parse the page - and retrieve the value of `href` attribute - this is the path of the icon.

Note also, that IE version 8 and below ignore this line completely and instead look for file `favicon.ico` in the root of the site.  See [this somewhat old article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon) for more information on IE.